# validation error webkit dropshadow

Tags: css

finished up a site that used the drop shadow in my css. I utilized the tools online to generate the syntax (http://css3generator.com/) Then when validating my site on jigsaw I repeatedly have been getting the validation error in reference to the drop shadow. I have done a little research and it seems to be rather common. However I would like some thoughts on different ways to get the same effect without validation errors, or if it is, in fact, alright to ignore them. Any thoughts or suggestions?

```css
.img_products {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: right;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, .75);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, .75);
}
```

Comment: could you post some code that is causing the issue.

Comment: sure, this is just a sample of one of the areas utilizing the drop shadow on an image

Comment: what validation? please share a link to the specific validation used.

Comment: what are the actual validation errors that are being reported?

Comment: The validation just says Property -webkit-box-shadow is an unknown vendor extension, which means it is behind the times.

Comment: After running through jigsaw, this is what comes up. 

Property -webkit-box-shadow is an unknown vendor extension

Comment: For me, this message is reported as 'Warning', not 'Error'. The validation result is "No errors found". The warning basically means that vendor-prefixed properties are usually experimental, but if you know what they do and what they are for, I think this warning isn't important.

Comment: So I assume it is fine to be ignored. Is there any reason for even adding it to the css, as I said before I used the code generator, and it was included.

Answer (score 2):

The jigsaw validator is just behind on it's vendor specific extensions. This is not an error.